# Using MediaWiki API with the Continue Command

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I need some help  Using  the Mediawiki API with the "Continue" or "query-continue" Command to pull information from my wiki articles.  I have a large number of wiki articles (more than 800 currently) and I need to use the api to pull them in batches of 50 and then print ou sections.

My API call works properly:

//Stackoverflow making me use a valid URL here, this api is actually my own localhost server
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=a&apto=z&apnamespace=0&format=xml&aplimit=50  I am querying all pages, therefore "apfrom" and "apto".

I just need help processing the code with PHP and CURL accessing the API and processing the batches of 50 and using the "continue" to access more records until I hit the end.  So far my  php code is:

```
  //the CURL commands here work and outputs a data set but only for the first 50 records, so I need to call "continue" to get to the end.  
 //My api url is localhost but I'm forced to use a valid URL by Stackoverflow.com
$url = sprintf('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?                                                                                            
 action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=a&apto=z&apnamespace=0&format=xml&aplimit=50');
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My site');
$res = curl_exec($ch);

$continue = '';

while ( // I don't know what to set here as true to get the while loop going, maybe continue                      = true? maybe set query-continue as true?) 
{
    //Maybe I need something other than $res['query-continue]??
    if (empty($res['query-continue'])) 
    {
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
        $continue = '&apcontinue='.urlencode($res['query-continue']);
            foreach ($res['query']['allpages'] as $v) 
            {
                echo $v['title'];
            }
    }
}
```

Can someone correct my while loop code above so I can do a simple print out of the title from each wiki article in the loop?  I've done a lot of searching online but I'm stuck!! I found a python loop example at  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query but I have to do it in PHP.   And I am not sure if I call continue or query-continue.

Comment: If you wanted to query all pages, don't set `apfrom` and `apto` at all. Not all page names have to start with a letter.

Comment: Also, why aren't you using one the [API libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#PHP)?

Comment: I am using the botclasses.php library but it doesn't have the query function that I need. Some of the other botclass libraries aren't working for me so I have to write my own function with continue.

Answer (score 2):

As svick said, please use a [client library](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code) which handles continuation for you.

The query continuation mechanism has changed multiple times in MediaWiki, you don't want to understand it or even less rely on it.